# Attempted to read or write protected memory in a .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g, iis-6, access-violation

I'm having troubles at implementing and ASP .Net Application in IIS 6 Server.

When the user tries to open a web page that access the database, iis server throws "Attempted to read or write protected memory" this is the StackTrace:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsPrm.ResetValCtx(OpoPrmValCtx* pOpoPrmValCtx, Int32 ctxSize)
>       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.ResetCtx(Int32 arraySize)
>       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection
>   conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
>       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
>       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
>       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
>       at Tenaris.FSA.OracleProvider.OracleProvider.ExecuteScalar(String commandToExecute, CommandType commandType, DbParameter[] parameters)
>   in C:\Congelados FSA\FSA 1er Entregable
>   05052013\Tenaris.FSA.OracleProvider\OracleProvider.cs:line 223
>       at Tenaris.FSA.DAC.Providers.DataAccessManager.ExecuteScalar(String
>   commandToExecute, CommandType commandType, DbParameter[] parameters)
>   in C:\Congelados FSA\FSA 1er Entregable
>   05052013\Tenaris.FSA.DataAccessComponent\Providers\DataAccessManager.cs:line
>   59
>       at Tenaris.FSA.DAC.Repository.AppointmentWayClientDAL.GetCountRegisters(Boolean
>   onlyEnabled) in C:\Congelados FSA\FSA 1er Entregable
>   05052013\Tenaris.FSA.DataAccessComponent\Repository\AppointmentWayClientDAL.cs:line
>   39
>       at Tenaris.FSA.BusinessComponents.BusinessProcess.AppointmentWayClientManager.GetCountRegisters(Boolean
>   onlyEnabled) in C:\Congelados FSA\FSA 1er Entregable
>   05052013\Tenaris.FSA.BusinessComponents\BusinessProcess\AppointmentWayClientManager.cs:line
>   28

What's rare, because that error is not supposed to appear in managed code, and the previous version of the site is working fine. I've done several tests, like compiling the app in an x86 platform pc, copied the web.config from the functional version, copied the Oracle.DataAccess dll from the functional version, but the error still showing.

Another thing you should know is that there is a page that, actually succeded in filling a dropdownlist, but then the page has to fill a gridview and there appears the above exception.

Comment: Check if restarting the server application (application on IIS 6 Server) will remove the bug ..... I have had the same problem ... sometimes happening and by restarting server the bug disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally solve the issue, another developer used a "using" clause while creating OracleParameters, it was like:

```
using(OracleParameter prm = SomeMethodThatCreatesIt(value,paramName))
{
 //extracode
 myCommand.Parameters.Add(prm);
}
```

So the code had to change to:

```
OracleParameter prm = SomeMethodThatCreatesIt(value,paramName);
//extracode
myCommand.Parameters.Add(prm);
```

As you can see in the stacktrace, the problem were at some process for parameters.

So, The code was Disposing the object before using it. What I can't understand is why is this even working in a console application that was one of my tests, but well it is working now, Thank you everyone

Answer (score -1):

the system has run out of ram to load it so when it tries to take more from other applications that is protected memory so get more ram